# DSolve[] does not provide the output I expect

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to use `DSolve`, however it is not giving me the output I expect.

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] + 5 y[x] == 1, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> 1/5 (1 - xy[x])}}
> ```

I have preceded this with `Clear["Global'*"]`

Comment: If I restart Mathematica and type `sol=DSolve[y'[x]+5 y[x]==1,y[x],x]` then I get  `{{y[x]->1/5+C[1]/E^(5*x)}}` and that is very different from what you get. Is that closer to what you expect? I am guessing that you have previously done some calculations and assigned something to some variables. Mathematica remembers those. Try starting Mathematica fresh and do that code before anything else and see if you get what I get. It would help people help you if you told them what you were expecting.

Comment: In 11.3 , `DSolve[y'[x] + 5 y[x] == 1, y[x], x]` returns `{{y[x] -> 1/5 + E^(-5 x) C[1]}}` . Besides, you may use `Clear["Global\`*"]`

Comment: `Clear["Derivative"]`